# If any element in the two lists is equal how can i write a error message?

Tags: python, list, if-statement, jupyter-notebook

Example i have 2 lists.

```
import string
character1= list(string.punctuation)
password=['a','b','1','@']
if(character1 in password):
    print("Error! Because you have a special character/characters in your password.Try again")
else:
    pass
```

How can i create a program like this? It isn't work in jupyter. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, `character1` in your code is a list and you are testing to see if this list is in the `password` list. You need to test whether there exists an element in `character1`  that is in `password`. One way to do this is to use the `any()` Python built-in function ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any)). `any()` accepts as an argument an iterable (in your case, a list) and "returns `True` if any element of the iterable is true". Below, this iterable argument is the generator `(i for password for i in character1)`.

```
if any(i in password for i in character1):
    print("Error! Because you have a special character/characters in your password.Try again")
else:
    pass
```